# How to purify water for shiv abhishek or Japa?

Tags: vedas, shiva, puranas, japa

If we keep water in copper vessel, and plan to use that water for `abhishek of shiva linga` or want to keep it `during japa`.

Here are the following questions:

1. What mantra to chant on the water?
2. What is the source(scripture reference) of that mantra?

Comment: While touching the water or pot with right hand (usually in Ankusha mudra) one recites the following mantra -- https://greenmesg.org/stotras/others/gange_ca_yamune_caiva.php

Comment: There is another purification mantra that can be recited ॐ अपवित्रः पवित्रो वा सर्वावस्थां गतोऽपि वा ।
यः स्मरेत्पुण्डरीकाक्षं स बाह्याभ्यन्तरः शुचिः ॥  https://greenmesg.org/stotras/vishnu/om_apavitrah_pavitro_va.php

Comment: The above is actually a Tirtha avahana mantra (used to invoke the presence of holy rivers in the water pot) rather than a water purifying mantra .. water is usually considered always pure.

Comment: That is for self purification not water purification @Just_Do_It

Comment: @Rickross It can be used to purify inner & outer elements. Also if you read गङ्गे च यमुने चैव ... it is usually used while bathing.

Comment: The one you gave is called marjana mantra .. its purpose is Atma Suddhi (Self purification) .. But here I think OP is asking about Jala Suddhi mantra and Gange cha mantra is used for that @Just_Do_It

Comment: Thanks @Rickross and Just_Do_It , 
Rickross , can you share some links for Ankusha mudra?

Comment: https://images.iskcondesiretree.com/index.php?sfpg=MDItLU11ZHJhJ3NfZm9yX0RlaXR5X1dvcnNoaXAvKkFua3VzaF9NdWRyYV8wMl9XLmpwZyoqaW1hZ2UqKjJmOGE3NDI2YjdlY2Y4ZWQ5ZTMzN2E3M2U5NjVhZTE0 @ArnabMukherjee

Comment: You can even simply touch the water pot with your fingers and chant the mantra